# cucumber ChildProcess::LaunchError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, cucumber

### The short story

I'm calling

```
bundle exec cucumber
```

and getting this error:

`` No such file or directory - -no-remote (ChildProcess::LaunchError) /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@ops/gems/childprocess-0.5.5/lib/childprocess/unix/fork_exec_process.rb:58:in `launch_process' ``

what could be causing this error?

### Details

I inherited a
website project:

- Runs on centos 6.6 server (nginx)
- ruby 1.9.3
- RVM
- ruby on rails 3.0.3
- javascript with extjs
- devise for security
- postgresql
- capistrano for deployment
- selenium, capybara, cucumber
- several more gems...

I was tasked with updating to latest versions of ruby, rails, and gems.  I followed [this guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) to upgrade the website.  the site (kinda) runs, and I'm debugging errors in it now.  I wanted to try and pass the automated cucumber tests that the previous developers created, and ran into this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learned the answer from the [childprocess github page](https://github.com/jarib/childprocess/issues/75):

```
# in ./features/support/env.rb
ChildProcess.posix_spawn = true
```

Likely the problem is that one of the many gems my website uses changes the semantics of Kernel#exec